# Server classes and client classes - multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm having some trouble in a couple of areas here.  First, when the array is printed to screen, the "P" is placed at [0][0] - which is OK, but it is surrounded by 'null' for any other cell.  I'd like it to be filled with dashes " - ".  I'm also needing to code in an infinite loop that asks the user to input either 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right' or 'exit'.  Does this infinite loop go into the "Driver" class, or the "World" class, and would a switch statement work for this?
Second - the rows and columns are not being summed and displayed.  The "World" class is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class World
{
    private static final String  P = "P";
    private String[][] array;

    public World()
    {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of row: ");
        int crow = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
        int ccol = input.nextInt();
        array = new String[crow][ccol]; 
        array[0][0]=P;
    }

    public void displayWorld()
    {
        System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " - ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }

    public void moveUp()
    {
       for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
                {
                    if (i < array.length - 1)
                    {
                        array[i][j] = " - ";
                        array[i - 1][j] = P;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveDown()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
                {
                    if (i < array.length - 1)
                    {
                        array[i][j] = " - ";
                        array[i + 1][j] = P;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveLeft()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
                {
                    if (i < array.length - 1)
                    {
                        array[i][j] = " - ";
                        array[i][j - 1] = P;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void moveRight()
    {
        for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
                {
                    if (i < array.length - 1)
                    {
                        array[i][j] = " - ";
                        array[i][j + 1] = P;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The "Driver" class is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Driver
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        World world=new World();
        world.moveUp();
        world.moveDown();
        world.moveLeft();
        world.moveRight();
        world.displayWorld();

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to split your question down into multiple questions each asking only one thing and containing only the information relevant to that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize every element in the array. Add this to the end of the `World` constructor:

```
   for(int i=0;i<crow;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ccol;j++){
            array[crow][ccol]="-";
        }
    }
```

You will need to add the infinite loop asking for input in the Driver class. In the infinite loop you need to:

1. Get input
2. Use switch statement to detect left, right, etc

Driver.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        World world = new World();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = s.nextLine();
            switch (input) {
            case "up":
                world.moveUp();
            case "down":
                world.moveDown();
            case "left":
                world.moveLeft();
            case "right":
                world.moveRight();
            }
        }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the coding as suggested and added the lines to get user input.  However, it is not moving the 'P' because for some reason the methods are not being called.  Won;t let me paste the new code to show the differences.